# CouchDb how best to execute a count(distinct) query where there are two "select" parameters

Tags: count, couchdb, distinct

What is the best way to do the following on a couchdb database?

`select count(distinct("some_field"))` where the `start_date_field>=date1` and `end_date_field < date2` ;

The start_date and end_date "fields" are not the same fields in the database.

Should I use a list?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but this should do what you are looking for:

I'm assuming your documents look something like this:

```
{
  "_id": "41210a75550b2a3d0daf6c1369fbd9e9",
  "_rev": "4-d2328d2aa75933bdba905f2d41361b87",
  "some_field": "abc12345",
  "start_date": "2015-01-02",
  "end_date": "2015-01-03"
}
```

You could write a map reduce function that looks like this:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.start_date && doc.end_date && doc.some_field) {
     emit([doc.start_date, doc.end_date, doc.some_field], 1);
  }
}
```

You would query the map reduce with the arguments something like this:

- `inclusive_end=true`
- `start_key=["2015-01-01", "\u0000", "abc12345"]`
- `end_key=["\ufff0", "2015-01-02", "abc12345"]`  <- end date minus one
- `reduce=true`
- `group=true`

`\u0000` and `\ufff0` represent some low and high unicode values.

Comment: I want a count of distinct values for "some_field" though then that field should not be in the start_key and end_keys.  Correct? Or should they also be the high and low unicode values respectively?

Comment: Ah, OK. So remove the some_field from the start and end keys and use group level to roll up the values.  I'm not able to check at the moment so let me know how you go.

Comment: i don't think it will won't work as I need to group on distinct values of "some_field" and count how many of those there are irrespective of date.  I could do a sum, but then if there are different docs with different dates and  the same "some_field" value the total will be wrong.

Comment: I think the "some_field" has to be first, then use a start_key of  ['\u0000', "2015-01-01", "\u0000"] and end_key of ['\ufff0, "\ufff0", "2015-01-02", {}]  then group by one (the first field) and do a count reduce.

Comment: Off the top of my head that could work.  Can you please post back to confirm.

Comment: Nope the distinct field has to be last.